# FullPage.js slider horizontal scroll breaks when scrollOverflow:true is set

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I had FullPage.js working perfectly for my site until I spent some time adding some additional content to one section. When I did that section became too big to fit in the viewport and so I set:

```
scrollOverflow: true
```

in the fullpage settings. When I did, my beautiful slider page stopped working. Now the content on each slide no longer displays properly.

- It shows more dots in the slider navigation than there are slides in
  the markup.
- The arrows are odd looking (double arrow on the left) and they don't respond when you click them.
- The content doesn't display at all for some slides.

I have played around with a few settings but couldn't get it working. The scroll overflow stuff is working though.

I would appreciate any help in the matter. I tried changing the content to each of the slides to something super super simplistic:

```
<p>hi</p>
```

but it still has the same unexpected behavior.

Here is a link to the live site for your perusal. [behavior demo](http://chirashi.watermintstudios.com/#3)

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are initializing fullpage.js multiple times.

Make sure you only initialize it once. Check you only import the plugin once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by my script being inside the fullpage DOM element. This is what it looked like:

```
<div id="fullpage">
  ...
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpageContainer').fullpage({ slidesNavigation: true, verticalCentered: false, paddingTop: 30, scrollOverflow: true });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

I had to change that to this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
  ...
</div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#fullpageContainer').fullpage({ slidesNavigation: true, verticalCentered: false, paddingTop: 30, scrollOverflow: true });
    });
</script>
```

Just a stupid mistake. Thanks for your help Alvaro, it helped me start looking in the right place for the problem.